# Get the value of an AttachedProperty of a UI item not (yet) displayed

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, binding

I'm trying to do the following using MVVM, Binding and AttachedProperty

- Create a ViewObj (System.Windows.Controls.Control derived class)

  - The ViewObj has 1 AttachedProperty named "Order" (OrderProperty) declared in a class named View.
  - The attached property is bound on a property of the ViewModel in the xaml
- Create the ViewModel
- Set the ViewModel as DataContext of the ViewObj

Before the ViewObj is displayed/rendered/etc.

- Get the order in code doing `var order = View.GetOrder(ViewObj)`
- The ViewObj is displayed and is showing the bound value ...

If the AttachedProperty is a value and not a binding expression, the value returned by `View.GetOrder(ViewObj)` is the good one and not the default one.

Any ideas?

### EDIT:

I forced the databinding expression to be evaluated using the `BindingExpression` class. I discovered that the `BindingExpression.Status` was set to `Unattached` which seems to explain why it is not working.

I think the binding is attached when the element is attached to the visual tree.

But ... that do not help me a lot with my problem ...

Comment: It would be easier to answer if there was source code in the post. What about question, you can use the PropertyChangedCallback when you register the property, then you will be allways notified about changes.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is the issue? Does the binding not work but assignment of absolute value works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that (in my case at least), the `Binding` was `Unattached`, but the `DataContext` was set.

So I decided to get the `DataContext` (the `ViewModel`) and to work with it.

Any others suggestions are welcome.